# Grouping pandas dataframe by two columns without summarizing it

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas Dataframe over the different states in America. I would like to group by the two columns *year* and *state* in order to statistically test some things e.g. cause of death, newborns etc. and also plot it.
I can only come up with the `groupby` pandas function where I have to specify a statistical summary in the end such as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path + 'csvfile.csv')
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Year', 'State']).mean()
```

However, I would like to just group by the *year* and *state* alone, but doing so with `groupby` I get this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path + 'csvfile.csv')
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Year', 'State'])

<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000025720134688>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean sort by? Use sort_values(['Year', 'State']) and see if you get what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `groupby` is simplifying like `iterator`, so is important what is after specify - aggregate function, custom function..?

---

Not sure what means `group by the year and state alone`, if need `MultiIndex` by 2 columns use:

```
grouped_df = df.set_index(['Year', 'State'])
```